# "OR" query in KeystoneJS Relationship Filters

Tags: filter, field, relationship, keystonejs

Currently, all I see examples for is:

```
{
   team: ':team'
}
```

But I need to be able to filter by multiple values ($or query)

Something like:

```
winner: {
   type: Types.Relationship,
   ref: 'Team',
   filters: [
      {
        _id: ':homeTeam'
      },
      {
        _id: ':awayTeam'
      }
   ]
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
filters:{_id:{$in:[id_array]}}
```